# Why doesn't this Typescript template literal type work?

Tags: typescript, generics, mapped-types

```
type WithAlpha<T> = `${T}A10`
```

throws this error:

"Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.

I really thought this was the most basic thing ever and it should work. What am I missing?

The plan was to use it with a series of union types to add the 'A10' to the end of each type within the union

Comment: Not all types are allowed to be serialized to strings in template literal types (as implemented in [ms/TS#30446](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)).  As the error implies, it will only allow you to serialize strings, numbers, booleans, nulls, and undefineds.  What sorts of types were you planning to pass as `T` into `WithAlpha<T>`? What's the use case?

Comment: Also, that is not a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), it's a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types); could you [edit] the question to use the standard terminology?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the clarification on the terminology, with that knowledge I was able to find the correct use in the documentation.
```ts
type WithAlpha<T extends number> = `${T}A10`
```

Comment: So you are only going to pass (unions of) numeric literal types into `WithAlpha`?  If so, could you say so in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast generic T to string literal by

`` type StringLiteral<T> = T extends `${string & T}` ? T : never; ``

and then:

`` type WithAlpha<StringLiteral<T>> = `${T}A10` ``